# RSA and format of numbers

Tags: rsa

When calculating the initial values of p,q,n, etc. in RSA, what base are the numbers? Are the numbers stored in binary, hex, or just simple base 10 when doing the modulus calculations?

Additionally, when it does encryption by block, what does that look like?

Answer (score 2):

Computers can only calculate in binary, as bits are base 2 by definition. Some advances have been made in storing or computing with more information in a "bit" but those systems have never been commercialized in the modern era to my knowledge.

Of course you can use base 2 calculations to perform operations in any base. Furthermore, the input and output can be *represented* to you in any format. If you look at a debugger you probably get presented numbers in either decimals or hexadecimals.

If you're really persistent you can of course perform RSA calculations manually. Generally you'd use decimals for that; at least that is what I've been thought.

---

RSA is generally not used for encryption block by block, look up *hybrid cryptosystems*. RSA is generally paired with a symmetric cipher such as AES, which does the bulk of the encryption for large messages.

Raw RSA is sometimes even performed letter-by-letter for practice only. RSA itself needs a padding scheme such as OAEP to be secure.